Show new connected (USB-) devices on desktop when connected to the PC
I remember in Ubuntu when i inserted a USB-Stick into my PC it would appear on the desktop as an icon afterwards. Now im Using Kubuntu 22.04 and I can't seem to find the option anymore. Is there a possibility for that?
